# What is the difference between "package" and "module" in Frege?

Tags: frege

Hi I've been playing a little bit with **Frege** and I just noticed in some examples that `package` and `module` are used interchangeably:

```
package MyModuleOne where
```

and sometimes:

```
module MyModuleTwo where
```

When importing from one or the other I don't see any difference in the behavior of my program. Is there something I should keep in mind when using `package` or `module` keywords ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It used to start out with `package`, but later I realized this was an obstacle when porting Haskell code which uses `module`. Hence I added `module`, and thus currently `module` and `package` are the same keyword, just spelled differently.

But the intention is, of course, to retire `package` sooner or later. So my advice would be to use `module` only.

(This reminds me that I probably have to update the lang spec with regard to this. Never mind.)